# Function_Check for registered instances in Maintenance Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-powershell

I have following code.

```
 function Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowMatch ([string]$instance,[string]$mwtag) {
  $mws = (Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowList -Region eu-central-1).WindowId
  for ($i=0; $i -le $mws.Length; $i++)  {
        $val = ((Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowTargets -WindowId $mws[$i]).Targets).Values
        $key = ((Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowTargets -WindowId $mws[$i]).Targets).Key
        if (($val -eq $instance) -and ($key -eq "tag:" +$mwtag)) {
        return $instance
        else {
          return $null
             }
      }
    }
}
```

I changed the code and just with instance it works but if i try to get the maintenance window tag additionaly to compare, it tells me

```
Get-SSMMaintenanceWindowTargets : 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'windowId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be 
null
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Also, 'I changed the code' means the code displayed is the current failing code?